# Hitting API which has no response in JSON nor in XML just returning the status code

Tags: android, retrofit2, no-data

I am having issue with the api call returning only status code not any json or xml response i am getting EOFException.

```
error - End of input at line 1 column 1 path $


**API**  - https://lo.convep.liveperson.net/api/account/3083754/chat/request.json?v=1
**Authorization** - LivePerson appKey=*********************
**Strict-Transport-Security** - **********
**Request** - {
    "request": {
        "LETagContextId": "1",
        "LETagSessionId": "XuUhaCCcR7Kk5lWHhNpFxA",
        "LETagVisitorId": "EwY2JmZmYzZTA1MDg3ODk2",
        "campaignId": "870922132",
        "engagementId": "870924032",
        "language": "en-US",
        "skill": "In App Chat"
    }
}

**response code getting - 201 created**
```

but don't get any data.

Please help how can i fix this in android using retrofit

```
 private fun requestChatLivePerson(urlChatRequest: String,visitorId: String?,sessionId: String?,contextId: String?,engagementId: String?, campaignId: String?, skillName: String?, language: String?) {
    val gson = Gson()
   Log.e("UrlChatRequest",""+gson.toJson(requestChatJson(visitorId, sessionId, contextId, engagementId, campaignId, skillName, language)))
    var requestChat = service?.requestChatLive(urlChatRequest,requestChatJson(visitorId, sessionId, contextId, engagementId, campaignId, skillName, language)
    )
    requestChat?.onResponse(object : Callback<ResponseChat> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseChat>, t: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Error while requesting chat..." + t.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show()
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseChat>, response: Response<ResponseChat>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                var responseBody = response.body()
                var headerList = response.headers()

                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Requesting Chat.Please wait for a moment....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Error while requesting chat...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }


    })
}
```

Interface Method :

```
@Headers("Authorization: LivePerson appKey=**********************",
         "Content-Type: application/json",
         "Strict-Transport-Security: ***************")
@POST
fun requestChatLive(@Url url: String, @Body requestJson: RequestChat): Call<ResponseChat>
```

Comment: removed could you plz help me with it....

Comment: code `201` means that your request has been processed correctly. If there is no response this means either: 1) there should be no response, as API has nothing to tell you except that everything was OK. 2) API is broken

Comment: yeah but when i am hiting this API i am getting eof exception because GSONCONVERTER not getting any data for parsing so how can i only read the status code as it is going in the failure callback method

Comment: you need to change your code that it does not expect anything JSON-related. But since you didn't show it - it's up to you to fix it.

Comment: now can u ??????

Comment: still not the code that has to be changed. `service?.requestChatLive`  needs to be cahnged

Comment: I solved the issue on my own thanks...